# How to download a plugin to disk for offline installation in IntelliJ

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea

I'm working with Intellij on an Windows machine without internet connection. How can I download a plugin from the repository (e.g. AngularJS) in order I can use the install from Disk feature?

Answer (score 5):

It is very simple, just download the plugin to the disk, which will generally be in the zip format. Now open Intellij and go to settings either by pressing Ctrl+Alt+S or from File menu. It will open the settings dialog. Follow below steps now

1. Select Plugins option from left nav in the dialog.
2. Click on the little gear icon at the top right corner as highlighted in red below.

[image]

3. Select "Install Plugin from Disk" option from the dropdown and choose the zip file you downloaded earlier and click Ok.
   *(Note: For some older versions of Intellij you will see "Install Plugin from Disk" button right at the bottom of the Plugins' window section itself.)*
4. Click on Apply button now and it will install the plugin.
5. Restart Intellij Idea.

Answer (score 4):

Go to the [plugin page](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/?idea), look for the version list. Every version has a "Download" link in the right column of the table.

Comment: What do you mean with "plugin page"? I checked in "Plugins" in the settings dialog and also in the "Browse repoistories..." dialog. I cannot see a Download (or any other) link at all.

Comment: Ok, page=https://plugins.jetbrains.com/?idea . I learned that the latest version often isn't the one that works. The correct version can be found in the plugin list of an Intellj installation that has the plugin already installed.